# Как связать скрипт нажатия кнопки и скрипт работы с содержимым страницы в расширении Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Сделал расширение, при клике на его иконку всплывает pop-up с кнопкой при нажатии на которую, открываются все ссылки на странице с определенным классом. Проблема в том, что расширение не работает со страницей, то есть не открывает ссылки с неё, а открывает ссылки только внутри себя (с файла popup.html). Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с popup.html запускался скрипт работы с содержимым страницы?

Вот код скрипта:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     let openScreensBtn = document.getElementById('btnScreens');
     openScreensBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      let links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
      let arrLinks = Array.from(links);
      let arrHref = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arrLinks.length; i++) {
        arrHref.push(arrLinks[i].getAttribute('href'));
      };
      for (let i = 0; i < arrHref.length; i++) {
        window.open(arrHref[i], '_blank');
      };
    });
  });
```

Вот код popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Index</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btnScreens">Open Screens</button>
</body>

</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Ext",
    "description" : "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: arrHref[i]});
```

При этом в `permission` (manifest.json) необходимо добавить разрешение на `tabs`.